# Define naming style as camelCase OR PascalCase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

Is it possible to define a naming style (in VS options or .editorconfig) as either `camelCase` *or* `PascalCase` (the programmer can write it either way, both are accepted), without disabling the whole check?

> The reason behind is that I would like to distinguish between fields that are there for technical reasons and should not be used, e.g. the backing field of a lazy initialized property, which I would write in `camelCase`, and fields that are there to be used (and which I do not like to convert into properties for performance, `ref` or other reasons), which I would like to write in `PascalCase`.

I tried the following in `.editorconfig`:

```
# Pascal-case style
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case

# Camel-case style
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization = camel_case

# Private fields (instance or static, constants etc.)
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private, internal

# Private fields are camelCase or PascalCase (incl. static)
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_pascal_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_pascal_case.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case_style
```

and this:

```
# Pascal-case style
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case

# Camel-case style
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization = camel_case

# Private fields (instance or static, constants etc.)
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private, internal

# Private fields are camelCase or PascalCase (incl. static)
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_any_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_any_case.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_be_any_case.style = camel_case_style, pascal_case_style
```

Comment: Rule of thumb is that private fields start with underscore _MyGlobalVar. Methods and Properties are PascalCase and local variables and parameters are camelCase. Don't know if that can be specified in editorconfig.

Comment: It can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules

Comment: ...but don't stray from fields being in camelCase, whether you use the leading underscore or not.

Comment: @madreflection: And how? All I read here on the liked page is that it is **not** possible, quoting _"You must specify a capitalization style as part of your naming style, otherwise your naming style might be ignored."_, and I see no possibility to combine capitalization styles or `OR`-concatenating naming rules. let me add what I have tried so far to my question...

Comment: @PaulSinnema That does not help. As I stated, a single style is not good enough for me, but I would be happy to live with a combination of `_technicalField` and `FieldToBeAccessed` combination if you know how to define that.

Comment: Same issue. We are trying to move from Resharper .DotSettings to .editorconfig but we can't replicate the flexible naming rules in Resharper that allows fields to be `_camelCase` or `_PascalCase`. We have a large code base with a lot of legacy so we need to support both styles.